# php move_uploaded_file unable to move

Tags: php, file-upload

I've got the following code to upload a file and add it to the folder called `images` located in the root of the server.

```
$file = $_FILES['prodImg']['tmp_name'];
$newLoc="/images/" . $_FILES['prodImg']['name'];  
if(move_uploaded_file($file, $newLoc)){
     //do some other code here
}
else{
     echo 'error';
}
```

the form has this button to add the image

```
<input type="file" name="prodImg" id="prodImg" accept="image/png" />
```

the `images` folder has all permissions set to read, write and execute
every time i try to upload an image it go to the `else` statement.
not sure what i'm doing wrong here.
how do i make it work properly?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($file, $newLoc)` is returning false and probably throwing an error. *If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.* Please paste the error if it gives any.

Comment: may be your file in exceeding size of 2mb, if it has set your php.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have attribute in your form?

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

I.e.:

```
<form action="..." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you can try to check permission for that folder.

And also try change filepath:

```
$newLoc="./images/" . $_FILES['prodImg']['name'];
```

or

```
$newLoc="images/" . $_FILES['prodImg']['name'];
```

Comment: This Works perfectly. i think the path was just incorrect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path of your `$newLoc` variable may be wrong. Try `./images/`.
The one specified may define an `image` folder on the same level as the `home`, `root`... folders if you use Linux.

Answer (score 0):

remove the slash ahead of images

```
$newLoc= "images/".$_FILES['prodImg']['name'];
```